# Manual plotly boxplot (not from data)

Tags: javascript, boxplot, plotly.js

To the best of my knowledge, a plotly boxplot (at least the default version, which should be equivalent to the generally accepted representation of a boxplot) is defined by 5 values:

```
q(0.0)    # The smallest outlier (= bottom whisker)
q(0.25)   # The first quartile (= bottom box base y-value)
q(0.5)    # The median (= horizontal line inside the box)
q(0.75)   # The third quartile (= top box base y-value)
q(1.0)    # The largest outlier (= top whisker)
```

These are the numbers that I believe plotly should compute when drawing a boxplot.

I posess a dataset on a `server` which contains too great (and ever increasing) amount of numbers which I'd like to visualize on a `client` using a boxplot (multiple datasets -> multiple boxplots actually, but irrelevant in the context of this question). I figured the best way to do this is to precompute those defining numbers, the `five-number summary` as they like to call it, on the server using special tricks and then simply passing the summary to the client, which can draw the boxplots easily, without me having to neither clog the bandwidth nor having the client do computational work everytime a request for visualization is handled. I hoped I could do this using `plotly` in `js`.

`Plotly` is great and it's (un?)fortunately strongly integrated into my project, so I'd like to avoid having to replace it for another vis tool.

Nonetheless, as far as I know, the `plotly` `boxplot` drawing function accepts a `list of data` (which is the expected use case), not really letting the user use his own precomputed summary allowing for low-level access to the `boxplot` visualization. I assumed I could bypass this easily though, because for

```
list_of_data = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

where `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` is any permutation of the five-number summary, the boxplot vis should be determined precisely by the summary. I found, however, that this is not the case. Plotly simply does not handle the `list of data` in this manner for reasons unknown (and unimaginable) to me, so I don't know how to start fixing this issue.

Ultimately, what I'd like to know, is how can I craft an artificial, small dataset (does not have to be in python ofc, I just need the algorithm)

```
def dataset_for_js_plotly(five_number_summary):
    ...
```

which results in `plotly` drawing precisely the boxplot corresponding to the summary, or if there indeed *is* a way to manually specify how the boxplot should look like in `js` `plotly`, and I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4220). The low-level access to boxplot calculations has been previously requested - for odd number of elements, there are multiple approaches to calculating Q1 (Q3 is mirrored). They are the following (sorry for the pseudopython).

Exclusive method:

```
def get_Q1_exclusive(data):
    N = len(data)
    data_l1 = get_lowest(data, N//2 - 1)
    return median(data_l1)
```

Inclusive method:

```
def get_Q1_inclusive(data):
    N = len(data)
    data_l2 = get_lowest(data, N//2)
    return median(data_l2)
```

Linear method (used by default for some reason):

```
def get_Q1_linear(data):
    l1 = get_Q1_inclusive(data)
    l2 = get_Q1_exclusive(data)
    return (l1 + l2) / 2
```

Luckily, it is possible to change the default method by adding a directive to the `data` parameter called `quartilemethod`:

```
Plotly.newPlot( ..., 
[
    {
        y: [2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 11, 11],
        type: 'box',
        quartilemethod: "inclusive" // or "exclusive" or "linear" (default)
    }
],
...
)
```

The overall solution to the problem is therefore keeping the original input array as it is, specifying `min`, `Q1`, `med`, `Q3`, and `max`, while using the `inclusive` method for Q1/Q3 computation. It works with my code, the change is minimal and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the box trace [reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/box/):

> The second signature expects users to supply the boxes corresponding Q1, median and Q3 statistics in the `q1`, `median` and `q3` data arrays respectively.

When using this second signature, you can also directly specify other statistics like the mean, std, lowerfence, upperfence, etc.

For instance,

```
var data = [
  {
    q1: [3, 1],
    median: [4, 2],
    q3: [5, 3],
    mean: [4.5, 2.5],
    sd: [1, 1],
    lowerfence: [0.5, 0.5],
    upperfence: [9, 8],
    type: 'box'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```